# "Which" or "what"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-usage, grammaticality

Which one is correct?

> - Do not pretend to perceive ***WHICH*** is not there.
> - Do not pretend to perceive ***WHAT*** is not there.

**Used in the following:**

> - What you don't know is that I feel pain in ways that you cannot seem
>     to be able fathom.
> - I understand the unwanted and abused.
> - I understand the victims and I understand the bullies.
> - I'm from both lands.
> - But let's get this one thing straight, you don't know anything about
>     me.
> - You know what I want you to think you know and that's it.
> - Do not pretend to perceive* **WHICH/WHAT** *is not there.

Comment: You might be able to figure this out on your own; there are [several columns](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=which+vs+what&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) written about this.

Comment: I think "that" is missing here. "that which is not there" /  "that what is not there". Or is it implied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"...perceive which is not there." is ungrammatical.

You could try "...perceive **that** which is not there." -- it's grammatical, although a bit formal/poetic.

"...perceive what is not there." is grammatical, and more colloquial.

However, "...perceive that what is not there." is not.